# How to open modal in phone gap using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile, phonegap-build

How to open modal(popup) after ajax call ??

my code was

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.1.24//ionic/search.php',
    type: "post",
    data: postdata,
    success: function (data) {

        $('#ScanModal').bind('click', function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
        $("#ScanModal").trigger("click");

    }
});
```

and html modal code is so need to open modal after ajax call please help me

```
 <a href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="popup" id="ScanModal" style="display:none">click</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="myPopupDialog" class="ui-dialog-contain ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header Text</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2>Welcome to my Popup Dialog!</h2>
        <p>jQuery Mobile is FUN!</p>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back">Go Back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what error you are getting right now ?

Comment: It not showing anything..but after response i am not able to open the jquery mobile popup

Comment: Is there any error in console ? have you tried this in browser ?

Comment: ya i tried in browser i check also..it not showing error

Comment: is this right url `http://192.168.1.24//ionic/search.php` because i dont think there is two // is possible after .24 ..

Comment: response coming into the ajax success block only.. I printed data also.Problem not with web service.After ajax success call i need to open jquery popup,I need to open what ever given in this site.http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_popups.asp

Comment: I tried  $('#ScanModal').click(); function in  ajax success call also.even it's not opening.

Comment: have a look at [w2school's](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_popups.asp) popup example. and
you don't need to trigger click you can directly open popup by `$("#myPopupDialog").popup('open');`